# How to check if a string == '\" (the literal character)

Tags: ruby

Here is my code in question

```
if (i == '*' || i == '\' || i == '+' || i == '-' )
```

But after much researching, I can't figure out how to simply check for the equality of `i == '\'`

Brownie points if you can guide me to a simpler solution. I want to parse a string and change any mathematical operators as such `+ -> :+, * -> :* ...etc` One idea I had in mind would be to have 4 `gsub()` functions, but that poses two problems (1) still have to find out how to check for equality with '\' and more importantly, (2) I feel like this is much code duplication and from what I hear that is a big stylistic 'no no' in Ruby.

Comment: have you tried escaping it? `'\\'`

Comment: Isn't `/` typically used for division? Does `a\b` translate to `b/a` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'\\'` is how you declare a string with a single character that is a `\`.

The reason you may think it isn't is because irb reports the `inspect` value of a string which includes quotes and escape sequences.

```
irb(main):010:0> '\\'
=> "\\"
```

However, if you use `puts` view the string instead, you'll see it's correct:

```
irb(main):012:0> puts "\\"
\
```

So you want:

```
i == '\\'
```

---

As for refactoring, I'd recommend an array of operator strings and then checking to see if that operator in in that array.

```
operators = ['+', '-', '*', '\\']

if operators.member? i
  # valid operator
end
```

---

But wait... isn't division typically `a/b` and not `a\b`? It's a forward slash to hint at numerator *over* denominator.  A backslash wouldn't make much sense. In fact the backslash is used as an escape character due it's near uselessness in most other contexts.

So you should be using `'/'` which contains no special characters, and works like you expect.

Comment: not sure how I made the `\` instead of  `/` , but thanks for the improved version! @Alex Wayne

Answer (score 3):

Try

`i == '\\'`

`\` is the [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), which means that it doesn't normally represent itself, but rather changes what happens to the character immediately following it.  For example, you can use it to place a single quote inside a single quoted string:

```
test = 'hello \'world\''
puts test
# ==> hello 'world'
```

or to add a newline in a double quoted string:

```
test = "hello\nworld"
puts test
# ==> hello
# world
```

So in order to use it by itself, you must escape it, leading to the double slash: `\\`.

As for a simpler if statement, how about

```
if %w{* \\ + -}.include?(i)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to parse a string and change any mathematical operators as such `+ -> :+, * -> :*` ...etc

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) would work:

```
puts 'a + b * c - d \ e'.gsub(/([+*-\\])/, ':\1')
```

Output

```
a :+ b :* c :- d :\ e
```